# Display "You Win" when I reach a certain Point in python using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to know how to Display a "You Win" and a picture at the end of the game when my player reaches 2000 score in the game. I also want to randomly display a hint when the player collides with the class Reseta. Below is my current code. Please be patient with me. Thank you!

```
import pygame
import os
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Chimera")
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576
SCREEN_WIDTH = 936
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

RUNNING = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_1.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_2.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_3.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_4.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_5.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_6.png"), (64,64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_side_right_7.png"), (64,64))]

JUMPING = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_jump_right.png"), (64,64))

DUCKING = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/slide3.png"), (64, 64)),
           pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/slide3.png"), (64,64))]

TREE = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Tree_1.png"), (64,140)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Tree_1.png"), (64,140)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Tree_2.png"), (64,140))]
BOX = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/box1.png"), (110,90)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/box2.png"), (110,90)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/box3.png"), (110,90))]

SHADOW = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Enemy_1.png"), (64,64)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Enemy_2.png"), (64,64)),]

PORTAL = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/portal_real.png"), (64,128)),
          pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/portal_real.png"), (64,128)),
          pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/portal_real.png"), (64,128))]

RESETA = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/reseta_real.png"), (45,120)),
          pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/reseta_real.png"), (45,120)),
          pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/reseta_real.png"), (45,120))]
DRUG = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Drug.png"), (45,90)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Drug.png"), (45,90)),
        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Drug.png"), (45,90))]

STANDING = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("images/Main1_front.png"), (64,64))
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "Background_2.jpg"))

class Boy:
    X_POS = 80
    Y_POS = 390
    Y_POS_DUCK = 430
    JUMP_VEL = 8.5

    def __init__(self):
        self.duck_img = DUCKING
        self.run_img = RUNNING
        self.jump_img = JUMPING

        self.boy_duck = False
        self.boy_run = True
        self.boy_jump = False

        self.step_index = 0
        self.jump_vel = self.JUMP_VEL
        self.image = self.run_img[0]
        self.boy_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.boy_rect.x = self.X_POS
        self.boy_rect.y = self.Y_POS

    def update(self, userInput):
        if self.boy_duck:
            self.duck()
        if self.boy_run:
            self.run()
        if self.boy_jump:
            self.jump()

        if self.step_index >= 10:
            self.step_index = 0

        if userInput[pygame.K_UP] and not self.boy_jump:
            self.boy_duck = False
            self.boy_run = False
            self.boy_jump = True
        elif userInput[pygame.K_DOWN] and not self.boy_jump:
            self.boy_duck = True
            self.boy_run = False
            self.boy_jump = False
        elif not (self.boy_jump or userInput[pygame.K_DOWN]):
            self.boy_duck = False
            self.boy_run = True
            self.boy_jump = False

    def duck(self):
        self.image = self.duck_img[self.step_index // 5]
        self.boy_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.boy_rect.x = self.X_POS
        self.boy_rect.y = self.Y_POS_DUCK
        self.step_index += 1

    def run(self):
        self.image = self.run_img[self.step_index // 5]
        self.boy_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.boy_rect.x = self.X_POS
        self.boy_rect.y = self.Y_POS
        self.step_index += 1

    def jump(self):
        self.image = self.jump_img
        if self.boy_jump:
            self.boy_rect.y -= self.jump_vel * 4
            self.jump_vel -= 0.8
        if self.jump_vel < - self.JUMP_VEL:
            self.boy_jump = False
            self.jump_vel = self.JUMP_VEL

    def draw(self, SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.boy_rect.x, self.boy_rect.y))
class Obstacle:
    def __init__(self, image, type):
        self.image = image
        self.type = type
        self.rect = self.image[self.type].get_rect()
        self.rect.x = SCREEN_WIDTH

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= game_speed
        if self.rect.x < -self.rect.width:
            obstacles.pop()

    def draw(self, SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image[self.type], self.rect)


class Box(Obstacle):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.type = random.randint(0, 2)
        super().__init__(image, self.type)
        self.rect.y = 380


class Tree(Obstacle):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.type = random.randint(0, 2)
        super().__init__(image, self.type)
        self.rect.y = 325


class Shadow(Obstacle):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.type = 0
        super().__init__(image, self.type)
        self.rect.y = 390
        self.index = 0


    def draw(self, SCREEN):
        if self.index >= 9:
            self.index = 0
        SCREEN.blit(self.image[self.index//5], self.rect)
        self.index += 1

class Drug(Obstacle):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.type = random.randint(0, 2)
        super().__init__(image, self.type)
        self.rect.y = 325


class Portal(Obstacle):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.type = random.randint(0, 2)
        super().__init__(image, self.type)
        self.rect.y = 300
class Reseta(Obstacle):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.type = random.randint(0, 2)
        super().__init__(image, self.type)
        self.rect.y = 350
def main():
    global game_speed, x_pos_bg, y_pos_bg, points, obstacles
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    player = Boy()
    # cloud = Cloud()
    game_speed = 10
    x_pos_bg = 0
    y_pos_bg = 0
    points = 0
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
obstacles = []
death_count = 0
def score():
    global points, game_speed
    points += 1
    if points % 500 == 0:
        game_speed += 1
    text = font.render("Points: " + str(points), True, (0, 0, 0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (850, 30)
    SCREEN.blit(text, textRect)
def background():
    global x_pos_bg, y_pos_bg
    image_width = BG.get_width()
    SCREEN.blit(BG, (x_pos_bg, y_pos_bg))
    SCREEN.blit(BG, (image_width + x_pos_bg, y_pos_bg))
    if x_pos_bg <= -image_width:
        SCREEN.blit(BG, (image_width + x_pos_bg, y_pos_bg))
        x_pos_bg = 0
    x_pos_bg -= game_speed
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    SCREEN.fill((255, 255, 255))
    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    background()
    player.draw(SCREEN)
    player.update(userInput)

    if len(obstacles) == 0:
        if random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
            obstacles.append(Box(BOX))
        elif random.randint(0, 2) == 1:
            obstacles.append(Tree(TREE))
        elif random.randint(0, 2) == 2:
            obstacles.append(Shadow(SHADOW))
        elif random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
            obstacles.append(Portal(PORTAL))
        elif random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
            obstacles.append(Reseta(RESETA))
        elif random.randint(0, 2) == 0:
            obstacles.append(Drug(DRUG))

    for obstacle in obstacles:
        obstacle.draw(SCREEN)
        obstacle.update()
        if player.boy_rect.colliderect(obstacle.rect):
            pygame.time.delay(2000)
            death_count += 1
            menu(death_count)
    score()

    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
def menu(death_count):
global points
run = True
while run:
    # SCREEN.fill((255, 255, 255))
    SCREEN.blit(BG, (0,0))
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)

    if death_count == 0:
        text = font.render("Press any Key to Start", True, (250, 245, 225))
        save = font.render("Score 1000 to save the Girl", True, (250, 245, 225))
        saveRect = save.get_rect()
        saveRect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 + 50)
        SCREEN.blit(save, saveRect)
    elif death_count > 0:
        text = font.render("Press any Key to Restart", True, (250, 245, 225))
        score = font.render("Your Score: " + str(points), True, (250, 245, 225))
        scoreRect = score.get_rect()
        scoreRect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 + 50)
        SCREEN.blit(score, scoreRect)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2)
        SCREEN.blit(text, textRect)

        SCREEN.blit(STANDING, (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2 - 20, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 140))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                main()
menu(death_count=0)
```

below is the file for the folder of images used in my game.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t_kDNw3G1Q6X4KKZ9IfsCmYKpEecz9Ci/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I created a little exemple for you. The only thing you have to remember is the purpose of the method `main_loop()` contained in my class Game (comments will help you to understand it). Just remember that you add several `while` loops that depends on a variable you will change in order to change state of the game. Each loop print out different things according to what is its goal.

For the point to reach, just create an invisible rect and check if your player rect collide with the invisible one. If it does, switch your variables in order to get into another loop that will print out something else than your game (in this case you could print out "You won".

For the score, you could add score every time the player does something and check every frame if the score exceed the score you have set to win. In this case, just switch variables in order to change state of the game.

```py
import pygame

# creating screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    """Defining a little class just to show the player on the screen"""

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize super class (pygame.sprite.Sprite)
        super().__init__()

        # defining rect of the player
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((100, 100), (100, 100))
        self.color = (255, 0, 0)

    def move_right(self):

        self.rect.x += 20

    def show_player(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)


class Game:

    """Defining the game class that contains the main loop and main variables"""

    def __init__(self):

        # defining variables for game loops
        self.running = True
        self.end_menu = False
        self.game = True

        # initialising player class
        self.pl = Player()

        # creating an invisible rect that the player has to reach
        self.reach_point = pygame.Rect((500, 100), (100, 100))

    def main_loop(self):
        
        """The goal here is to create several loops. One will be for the main game loop that will contains 
        the two other loops (as many as you want), when an event you chose will happens, the variable that makes
        the loop run will turn on false and the variable that makes the loop of the other stage you want to reach
        will turn on true. So you will constantly run a loop because your main loop will end up only if you quit the
        game."""
        
        while self.running:

            while self.game:

                for event in pygame.event.get():

                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        self.running = False
                        self.game = False

                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                        # defining just a key for the example
                        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                            self.pl.move_right()

                # detecting if the player reach the invisible rect
                if self.pl.rect.colliderect(self.reach_point):
                    self.game = False
                    self.end_menu = True

                # fill the screen in white
                screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

                # shows the player
                self.pl.show_player()

                # update the screen
                pygame.display.flip()

            while self.end_menu:

                for event in pygame.event.get():

                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        self.running = False
                        self.end_menu = False

                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                        if event.key == pygame.K_p:

                            self.game = True
                            self.end_menu = False

                # fills the screen in order to see the different states of the game
                screen.fill((255, 255, 0))

                # update the screen
                pygame.display.flip()


# initializing the class game
game = Game()

pygame.init()

# calling function `main_loop()` contained in the class Game (initialised as game)
game.main_loop()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Note that I could have wrote it quite shorter but it's better to get good habits of coding. POO is one of these.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way that you can have a "You Win" show up in your game when the score reaches 200. You would need a variable for the score that increases every time something happens. First, you would have to load an image for the "You Win" by doing `pygame.image.load(file name.png)` then you would have to assign variables for the x-axis and y-axis of the image (I used You_WinX and You_WinY for the example) then you can simply do this:

```
if score == 2000:
     You_WinX = (location on x-axis)
     You_WinY = (location in y-axis)
```

What this would do is when the score reaches the value of 2000, the image of "You Win" will appear where you want it to be on the screen (x,y)